# Rails how to set table in find command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

After migrating from Rails 3.2.12 to 4.0.0 this dosn't work any more

```
@course = @current_client.courses.find params[:id], :conditions => ["active = ? AND bookable = ?", true, true]
```

The Problem is that it tries to get data from table

```
clients_course_objects
```

right table should be

```
clients_course
```

Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails 4 way to run this query is:

```
@current_client.courses.where("active = ? AND bookable = ?", true, true).find(params[:id])
```

Comment: thanks but got the same error, it tries to find from `clients_course_objects` but the right table should be `clients_courses` ...

Comment: It seem like you have something overriding the table name on that model.  I don't think this is a Rails 4 issue.

Comment: hmm and how can I figure it out? do you have some hints?

Comment: Show us the code for your Client and Course models.

Comment: oh I have fixed it lol .... i had this: `has_and_belongs_to_many :courses` and added this: `:join_table => "clients_courses"`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
@course = @current_client.courses.where("id = ? AND active = ? AND bookable = ?", params[:id], true, true)
```